# Navigation Bar content is not displayed properly

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why I added `display: none` in the `.third-level` drop down content but it doesn't being hidden as expected when I'm hovering on the second level content and got displayed all at once. Also all the `.third-level` content got overlapped on each other too. I don't know if I'm wrong (should be wrong :/) or missing something. Thanks in advance!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Space Mono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.eot');
  src: local('Space Mono'), local('SpaceMono-Regular'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/space-mono-v4-latin-regular.svg#SpaceMono') format('svg');
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    background: #000;
  background: url(Galaxy.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 150px 0px 0px 120px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 120px;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 50px;
    color: #fff;
  text-indent: 50px;
  width: 720px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
}

.first-level {
    font-size: 24px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: -60px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.first-level a {
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.first-level li {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.first-level li:hover {
    background-color: teal;
}

.first-level li:hover ul {
    display: inline;
}

.second-level {
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.second-level li {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.second-level li:hover {
    background: teal;
}

.third-level {
  position: absolute;
    display: none;
  top: 0px;
  right: -200px;
    width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.third-level li {
    position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.third-level li:hover {
    background: teal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NavigationBar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="newnavbar.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
  <body>

    <ul class ="first-level">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 1-5</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 1</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 2</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 4</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 5</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#">LAB 6-8</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 6</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 7</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 8</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 9-11</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 9</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 10</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 11</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 12-14</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 12</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 13</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 14</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>

        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>(Placeholder text).</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.first-level li:hover > ul` used > instead of `.first-level li:hover  ul`.
`.first-level li:hover  ul` this will select all the `ul` inside `.first-level`
`.first-level li:hover > ul` selects all `ul` elements where the parent is a  `.first-level`

below is the link which help you to understand the css selectors. Hope this helps. thanks.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Space Mono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.eot');
  src: local('Space Mono'), local('SpaceMono-Regular'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('space-mono-v4-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/space-mono-v4-latin-regular.svg#SpaceMono') format('svg');
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
 background: #000;
  background: url(Galaxy.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 150px 0px 0px 120px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 120px;
 padding: 20px 0px 20px 50px;
 color: #fff;
  text-indent: 50px;
  width: 720px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-left: 4px solid #fff;
}

.first-level {
 font-size: 24px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin: -60px 0px 0px 0px;
 position: sticky;
 top: 10px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.first-level a {
 text-decoration: none;
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #fff;
}

.first-level li {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 height: 60px;
 width: 200px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.first-level li:hover {
 background-color: teal;
}

.first-level li:hover > ul {
 display: inline;
}

.second-level {
  position: absolute;
 display: none;
  top: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.second-level li {
 position: relative;
 height: 60px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.second-level li:hover {
 background: teal;
}

.third-level {
  position: absolute;
 display: none;
  top: 0px;
  right: -200px;
 width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.third-level li {
 position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.third-level li:hover {
 background: teal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NavigationBar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="newnavbar.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
  <body>

    <ul class ="first-level">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 1-5</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 1</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 2</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 4</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 5</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href="#">LAB 6-8</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 6</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 7</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 8</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 9-11</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 9</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 10</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 11</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">LAB 12-14</a>
            <ul class ="second-level">
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 12</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 13</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href ="#">LAB 14</a>
                    <ul class ="third-level">
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="#">Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </ul>

        <h2>CSC 212 - Spring 2019.</h2>
        <p>This site represents work that I have done in support of my
           efforts to learn to program in the CS1 course at SUNY Oswego
           during the Spirng 2019 semester. The materials will be temporally
           organized for the most part. Links to external sites that pertain
           to computer programming, problem solving, Java, Web development,
           and related matters will be placed after the personally created
           artifacts.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!